# POST request does not return form dropdown value in Node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using a form which consists of an email text input and a drop down however when I submit using a post request, the request body only returns the email id.

**index.hbs**

```
<form method="post" action="/query" novalidate>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="Type">Type</label>
        <div class = "form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6 dropdown">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
                    <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Activity 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Activity 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Activity 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input class="input" id="email" name="email" type="email" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**index.js**

```
router.post('/query', function(req, res){
   res.render('shop/query', {
       data: req.body,
       errors: {
           message: {
               msg: "An error occurred"
           },
           email:{
               msg: 'That email does not look right'
           }
       }
   });
   console.log(req.body);
});
```

The terminal displays something like this

```
{ email: 'example@gmail.com' }
```

Whereas it should display the activity selected from the drop down as well.

I have tried various ways however I cannot understand where I am going wrong. Also is there a technique to improve this method and make the details selected in the form appear in the url as a parameter and then use something like this to get the details

```
router.get('/add-to-cart/:id', function(req, res, next){
  var productId = req.params.id;
```

Comment: Only form element will be sent to server when you submit form, you may refer https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp

Comment: form elements have "name" attribute, so only email is getting to the server... if you want to get dropdown value, maybe you should make post manually. Regards

Comment: @Albeis I added a name tag to every element however it is yet not coming in the console. Could you elaborate more on how to post manually

Comment: @rut_0_1 - You would benefit from reading the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects